# Python Return Start/Stop Indices of Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given this list:

```
a = ['a','b','b','b','c','c','d','e','e']
```

I would like to return a list of lists, each one containing start and stop indices of values like so:

```
[[0,0], [1,3], [4,5], [6,6], [7,8]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
a = ['a','b','b','b','c','c','d','e','e']

from itertools import groupby

last_index = 0
out = []
for v, g in groupby(enumerate(a), lambda k: k[1]):
    l = [*g]
    out.append([last_index, l[-1][0]])
    last_index += len(l)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 3], [4, 5], [6, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

using both [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) we can avoid accumulating the index ourselves.

also, this doesn't add extra data for every element in the original array, but rather just to every group.

try this:

```py
from itertools import groupby, accumulate

a = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e']

lens = [len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(a)]
result = [[accumulated_length-current_length, accumulated_length-1] for current_length, accumulated_length in zip(lens, accumulate(lens))]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 3], [4, 5], [6, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is sorted

```
if len(a) == 0:
  return []
result = []
firstSeenIndex, elementInWatch = 0,a[0]
for i,ele in enumerate(1,a[1:]):
    if ele == elementInWatch:
       continue
    else:
       result.append([firstSeenIndex,i-1])
       firstSeenIndex = i
       elementInWatch= ele
result.append([firstSeenIndex,len(a)-1]
return result
```

Note: There are much better ways to do it, I hope this is intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
def start_stop_indice(a):
    result = []   # init empty list
    start_inx,end_inx,count = 0,0,0 # init indexs and counts to 0

    # while the starting index plus the count of records <= the length of the list
    while start_inx + count <= len(a): 
        # count is the number of times a record is in the list
        count = a.count(a[start_inx])  

        # end_index is the starting index + number of occurances - 1
        end_inx = start_inx + count - 1 

        # append a list of starting and ending indexs to the results list
        result.append([start_inx,end_inx]) 

        # add the count to the starting index to get next value
        start_inx += count

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ['a','b','b','b','c','c','d','e','e']
    print(start_stop_indice(a))
```